# If $f \in L^1_{loc}$ then $\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} A_r f(x) = f(x)$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is Theorem 3.18 in Folland. I am having trouble following one detail of his proof. His proof is as follows:

> It suffices to show that for $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_rf(x) \rightarrow
> > f(x)$ for a.e. $x$ with $|x| \leq N$. But for $|x| \leq N$ and $r \leq 1$ the values $A_r f(x)$ depend only on the values $f(y)$ for $|y| \leq N + 1$, so by replacing $f$ with $f_{\chi_{B(N+1, 0)}}$ we may
> assume that $f \in L^1$.
>
> Given $\epsilon > 0$, by Theorem 2.41 we can find a continuous
> integrable function $g$ such that $\int |g(y) - f(y)| \,dy < \epsilon$
> . Continuity of $g$ implies that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and
> $\delta > 0$ there exists $r > 0$ such that $|g(y) - g(x)| < \delta$
> whenever $|y-x| < r$, and hence  $$ |A_r g(x) - g(x)| =
> \frac{1}{m(B(r,x))} \Big| \int_{B(r,x)} [g(y) - g(x)] \,dy \,\Big| < \delta$$
>
> where
>
> $$A_rg(x) = \frac{1}{m(B(r,x))} \int_{B(r,x)}g(y)\,dy.$$
>
> Therefore $A_rg(x) \rightarrow g(x)$ as $r \rightarrow 0$ for every
> $x$, so $$\limsup_{r\rightarrow 0} |A_r f(x) - f(x)| = \limsup_{r
> \rightarrow 0} |A_r(f-g)(x) + (A_rg - g)(x) + (g-f)(x)| \leq H(f-g)(x) + 0 + |f-g|(x)$$
>
> where $Hf$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $f$.
>
> Hence, if  $$E_\alpha = \{x : \limsup_{r \rightarrow 0} |A_rf(x) -
> f(x)| > \alpha\}, \quad F_\alpha = \{x : |f-g|(x) > \alpha\}$$ we have
> $$E_\alpha \subset F_{\alpha/2} \cup \{x : H(f-g)(x) > \alpha/2\}.$$
>
> But  $$(\alpha/2)m(F_{\alpha/2}) \leq \int_{F_{\alpha/2}} |f(x) -
> g(x)| \,dx < \epsilon$$ so by the maximal t heorem,  $$m(E_\alpha)
> \leq \frac{2\epsilon}{\alpha} + \frac{2C\epsilon}{\alpha}.$$
>
> Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $m(E_\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha > 0$.
> But $\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} A_r f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \not\in
> \bigcup_1^\infty E_{1/n}$, so we are done.

There are two details which are not clear to me. First, it was shown that $|A_rg(x) - g(x)| < \delta$, but how does it follow that $A_r(g)x \rightarrow g(x)$ as $r \rightarrow 0$? And second, how does it hold that
$$E_\alpha \subset F_{\alpha/2} \cup \{x : H(f-g)(x) > \alpha/2\}?$$

I believe the rest of the proof seems clear and I can follow it, but some intuition behind how one would come up with such a proof would be very helpful as well. I have already seen [Real Analysis, Folland Theorem 3.18 Differentiation on Euclidean Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863921/real-analysis-folland-theorem-3-18-differentiation-on-euclidean-space), but am still unclear on these details.

Comment: For completeness, can you include the statement of the theorem?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Sorry I should have specified, but the title of the post is the theorem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first part in a bit more detail:
$$\begin{align}
|A_r g(x) - g(x)| &= \frac{1}{m(B(r,x))} \left| \int_{B(r,x)} g(y) - g(x) dy \right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{m(B(r,x))} \int_{B(r,x)}\left|  g(y) - g(x)  \right| dy \\ 
&\leq \frac{1}{m(B(r,x))} \sup_{y \in B(r,x)} |g(y) - g(x)| \int_{B(r,x)}1dy \\
&= \sup_{y \in B(r,x)} |g(y) - g(x)| \\
&\to 0
\end{align}$$
as $r \to 0^+$, where the limit follows from the continuity of $g$ at $x$.

The second part is an application of the previous inequality.
That is, given that we know $$\limsup_{r \to 0} |A_r f(x) - f(x)| \leq H(f-g)(x) + |f(x) - h(x)|$$
if $x$ is such that $\limsup_{r \to 0} |A_r f(x) - f(x)| > \delta$, then either $H(f-g)(x) > \frac{\delta}{2}$ or $|f(x) - h(x)| > \frac{\delta}{2}$; otherwise,
$$\delta < \limsup_{r \to 0} |A_r f(x) - f(x)| \leq H(f-g)(x) + |f(x) - h(x)| \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! Your proof seems to suggest it is okay for both $H(f-g)(x) > \frac{\delta}{2}$ and $|f(x) - h(x)| > \frac{\delta}{2}$, is that correct? I believe the wording in Folland's proof made it seem like this condition was exclusive and that might be the source of my confusion.